# Is there a way of opening a NFC tag url inside the app, instead of google/safari?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, nfc

I am developing an Android app using Kotlin and it is supposed to read the NFC tag, start my app and open the URL inside of the app.

However, whenever I am inside the app and I tap the NFC tag it opens Chrome. It is supposed to open the URL inside of it.

Here is my activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var TAG = "NFC supported"
    var TAG2 = "NFC enabled"
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)
        Log.d("NFC supported", (nfcAdapter != null).toString())
        Log.d("NFC enabled", (nfcAdapter?.isEnabled).toString())

        if (intent != null) {
            processIntent(intent)
        }

        val intent = Intent(this, javaClass).apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
        }
        var pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)


        val ndef = IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED).apply {
            try {
                addDataType("*/*")    /* Handles all MIME based dispatches.
                                 You should specify only the ones that you need. */
            } catch (e: IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException) {
                throw RuntimeException("fail", e)
            }
        }


        var intentFiltersArray = arrayOf(ndef)

        val techListsArray = arrayOf(arrayOf<String>(NfcF::class.java.name))

    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?){
        super.onNewIntent(intent)

        if(intent != null){
            processIntent(intent)
        }

    }

    private fun processIntent(checkIntent: Intent) {
        if(checkIntent.action == NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED) {
            val rawMessages = checkIntent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES)
        }
    }
}
```

Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `enableForegroundDispatch` to receive NFC Intent's when your App is in the foreground, the Manifest Filters is just to tell the System you want your App to be in the list of App to be consider to be launched when it sees a Tag of the correct type and your App is not running (Then the Intent should be processed in `onCreate`

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc#foreground-dispatch

So create the Pending Intent and correct Intent Filers and enable/disable Foreground dispatch in `onResume` and `onPause`, once that is done Tag's seen while running will be delivered to `onNewIntent`

**Update:**
There looks nothing wrong with the documentation parts, but you still have not quite put it together correct.

So I've taken your code and re-arranged it a bit to show a fully working example (and tested with an NFcA NDEF tag)

```kotlin
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter
import android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var TAG = "NFC supported"
    var TAG2 = "NFC enabled"

    private var nfcAdapter : NfcAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)
        Log.d("NFC supported", (nfcAdapter != null).toString())
        Log.d("NFC enabled", (nfcAdapter?.isEnabled).toString())

        if (intent != null) {
            processIntent(intent)
        }

    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?){
        super.onNewIntent(intent)

        if(intent != null){
            processIntent(intent)
        }

    }

    private fun processIntent(checkIntent: Intent) {
        if(checkIntent.action == NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED) {
            val rawMessages = checkIntent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES)
            Log.d("processIntent", "NDEF Found")
        }
    }

    public override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        nfcAdapter?.disableForegroundDispatch(this)
    }

    public override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val intent = Intent(this, javaClass).apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
        }
        var pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)


        val ndef = IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED).apply {
            try {
                addDataType("*/*")    /* Handles all MIME based dispatches.
                                 You should specify only the ones that you need. */
            } catch (e: IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException) {
                throw RuntimeException("fail", e)
            }
        }


        var intentFiltersArray = arrayOf(ndef)

        val techListsArray = arrayOf(arrayOf<String>(NdefFormatable::class.java.name))
        nfcAdapter?.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFiltersArray, techListsArray)
    }

}
```

Note I changed from `NfcF` to `NdefFormatable::class.java.name` in the techlist as this is more useful if only dealing with NDEF type data (As NFcF type tags are less common) but really if the NFC Tag has NDEF data on it the this can valve can be set to `null` in the `enableForegroundDispatch` call

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment Andrew, I have read that documentation, however, I get two errors on the b and c part of that Dispatch system. I have edited my code, if you could so kindly take a look at it.